# Get longest name in a list of names

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example be like:

```
def get_longest_name(a_list):
    count = 0
    for i in a_list:
        if len(i) > count: 
           count = len(i)
           word = i
    return word
def main():
    print("1.", get_longest_name(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath", "Amity", 
   "Raeanne"]))
    print("2.", get_longest_name(["Josephine", "Jessie", "Penelope", "Jin", 
  "Rosamunda", "Annabelle"]))
    print("3.", get_longest_name(["Alan", "Jess", "Amity", "Rosalie", 
  "Raeanne"]))
    print("4. ", "***", get_longest_name(["Jo", "Jai", "Jen", "Jing", "Joey", 
   "Jess"]), "***", sep = "")
    print("5. ", "***", get_longest_name([]), "***", sep = "")
    print("6.", "***" + get_longest_name([""]) + "***")
main()
```

output like:

```
1. Candide
2. Josephine
3. Rosalie
4. ***Jing***
```

I already get three correct output(three longest names), but for 4th output, there is no longest name exist, and also for 5th,6th.I expect the output be like:

```
 1. Candide
 2. Josephine
 3. Rosalie
 4. ******
 5. ******
 6. ******
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation (e.g. after the `if` statement). I get a `UnboundLocalError` for `5`. I don't understand are you looking to hide `Jing` with `******` - looks like you have a condition to check.

Comment: It hit an error, and exited. You need a debugger, or read the errors. Initialize word=None at the start, otherwise you try to return an undefined variable. If you want ties to return nothing, then you'll have to handle that case with something like if len(i) == count: word=None

Comment: Wait, why should it return None or blank for multiple four letter names, but it's okay to return "Rosalie" over "Raeanne"? Something's not right with the question.

Comment: as well as `Candide` and `Raeanne`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use the built-in `max()` function:

```
>>> max(["Candide", "Jessie", "Kath", "Amity", "Raeanne"], key=len)
'Candide'
```

Comment: I like it, but OP wants an unusual handling for ties. max won't give that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You’re vague about the output you want to achieve. Unlike what you said, Candide and Raeanne are of equal length. Likewise, there’re names of equal length in 2nd and 3rd cases. In the 4th, there’re three names of same length.

Assuming you want to output `‘******’` for [], [‘’] and for a list containing names of equal length, or the name that is greater in length than any other name in a list, here’s my code:

```
def get_longest_name(a_list):
    longest_name = '******'

    if not a_list:
        return longest_name

    max_length = max([len(name) for name in a_list])
    duplicate_lengths = [name for name in a_list if len(name) == max_length]

    if a_list == [''] or len(duplicate_lengths) > 1:
        longest_name = longest_name
    else:
        longest_name = ''.join(duplicate_lengths)

    return longest_name
```

Answer (score 0):

So , Here already good solutions but if you want to create logic for yourself for finding max and if not max then printing ("******") without using built-in max() function then take a look :

Let's solve your problem in three step:

for testing purpose suppose list is :

```
word_list=["Jo", "Jai", "Jen", "Jing", "Joeyr",
       "Jess"]
```

> First step :

suppose you want that if three character len are same then print("******") so first we have to filter out how many characters in list have same length and if more than three have same length then print("******") now for filtering we could use filter , lambda and list comprehension but here i will use very simple and readble approach :

```
    len_of_characters=[]   #we will store len of characters in this list 
    more_than_3=[]         #we will store that int in this list 



for i in word_list:
    len_of_characters.append(len(i))
    for check in len_of_characters:
        if len_of_characters.count(check)>2:
            more_than_3.append(check)
```

Good job now we are moving to step two :

> Second Step :

We have checked that if a list have more than three same len character then add that len to a list called more_than_3 now we are going to see second part of this issue suppose if list doesn't have same length character then we want to stroe longest word character in that list so:

```
longest_word=[]        #we will store longest len word here

count_number = 0

for i in word_list:
    if more_than_3:

        print("******")
        break

    else:
        if len(i) > count_number:
            count_number = len(i)
            word = i
```

Now we have done all the logic part which this problem requires , now let's do last part which will check if more_than_3 list is empty than print longest word and if more_than_3 is not empty than print ("******") , very simple :

```
try:
    longest_word.append(word)
except NameError:
    pass

if not more_than_3:
    print("".join(longest_word))
```

All combine :

```
word_list=["Jo", "Jai", "Jen", "Jing", "Joeyr",
   "Jess"]

count_number = 0

longest_word=[]






len_of_characters=[]
more_than_3=[]

for i in word_list:
    len_of_characters.append(len(i))
    for check in len_of_characters:
        if len_of_characters.count(check)>2:
            more_than_3.append(check)

for i in word_list:
    if more_than_3:

        print("******")
        break

    else:
        if len(i) > count_number:
            count_number = len(i)
            word = i
try:
    longest_word.append(word)
except NameError:
    pass

if not more_than_3:
    print("".join(longest_word))
```